# Get specific XML Subvalues with Commons Configuration

Tags: java, xml, xpath, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

Lets say we have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <sub>
        <id>1</id>
        <values>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>2</value>
        </values>
    </sub>
    <sub>
        <id>2</id>
        <values>
            <value>16</value>
            <value>15</value> 
        </values>
    </sub>
</root>
```

What I want to with Apache Commons Configuration: I want to get all values for `sub` with `id`2. How could I achieve that? I find nothing in the documentation, how I can query with a dynamic hierarchy number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
//sub[id = 2]/values/value
```

Comment: Awesome, that was quick. Works perfectly. Seems like the documentation could be improved at this topic :)

Answer (score 1):

`//` often leads to slow execution (causes the whole XML (sub) tree to be searched).

**Use**:

```
/*/sub[id = 2]/values/value
```

This selects any `value` element that is a child of a `values` element that is a child of a `sub` element whose `id` child has string value `"2"`, and that (the `sub`) is a child of the top element of the XML document.

Comment: Thanks, that could be very useful when dealing with large xml configs